# Those who have implemented Apple Pay - your server for token auth - Stripe for processing, how would you diagnose code 50 error?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

For some reason the token isn't getting set to my server. I get code 50 as a print error, but I can't seem to narrow it down. Do any of you have any idea? Below you will see all the prints that I added to try to figure out where the problem is coming from. Basically the `applePayContext(_:didCreatePaymentMethod:paymentInformation:completion:)` delegate method is not being called. Why that is I don't know. All I have is error code 50. I checked merchant id in Xcode and on my developer account I have it all set up. In my class I have `STPApplePayContextDelegate` and I have `var paymentContext: STPApplePayContext?`

```
    @objc func applePayButtonTapped() {
    print("Apple Pay button tapped")
    let request = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: "merchant.medical.daylike", country: "US", currency: "EUR")
    request.paymentSummaryItems = [PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Script", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "1.00"))]
    print("Payment request details: \(request)")
    paymentContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: request, delegate: self)
    print("Presenting Apple Pay sheet")
    paymentContext?.presentApplePay()
    
    print("yesue")
}
    
func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCreatePaymentMethod paymentMethod: StripePayments.STPPaymentMethod, paymentInformation: PKPayment, completion: @escaping StripeApplePay.STPIntentClientSecretCompletionBlock) {
    
    print("Apple Pay did create payment method")
    let paymentMethodId = paymentMethod.stripeId
    let amount = 100 // Example amount in cents (€10.00)
    
    createPaymentIntent(paymentMethodId: paymentMethodId, amount: amount) { result in
        
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let clientSecret):
            completion(clientSecret, nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in creating payment intent: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
    
    
}

func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didFailToCreatePaymentMethodWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to create payment method: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didCompleteWith status: StripePayments.STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
    print("Apple Pay process didCompleteWith status: \(status)")
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        print("Error in Apple Pay process: \(error.localizedDescription), Code: \(error.code)")
    }

    print("Apple Pay process completed with status: \(status)")
    switch status {
    case .success:
        // Payment succeeded
        break
    case .error:
        // Payment failed
        break
    case .userCancellation:
        // User canceled the payment
        break
    @unknown default:
        fatalError("Unknown Apple Pay status")
    }
}
```

My prints

```
Payment request details: <PKPaymentRequest: 0x14bde0f80; APIType: PKPaymentRequestAPITypeInApp, requestType: PKPaymentRequestTypeApplePay, requestor: PKPaymentRequestorDefault, countryCode: DE, merchantCapabilities: 1, currencyCode: EUR, shippingType: SHIPPING, applePayLaterAvailability: enabledshouldUseMerchantSession: 0, suppressTotal: 0, paymentSummaryPinned: 0, supportedNetworks: (
    AmEx,
    MasterCard,
    Maestro,
    Visa,
    Discover
), supportsCouponCode: 0, paymentSummaryItems: 1, requiredBillingContactFields: {(
    post
)}, >
Presenting Apple Pay sheet
yesue
Apple Pay process didCompleteWith status: error
Error in Apple Pay process: There was an unexpected error -- try again in a few seconds, Code: 50
Apple Pay process completed with status: error
```

Comment: is this on a simulator or a physical device? what version of iOS, what version of the Stripe SDK? >> Did you upload your processing certificate to Stripe's Dashboard (https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay?platform=ios#csr) ? << Are there errors in your Stripe logs? https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs